# How can I get a typesafe POJO of actions mapped to a string from a Slice (redux toolkit)

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to setup a function that returns a typesafe POJO of a Slice's action names mapped to the corresponding action type name (using the convention of sliceName/sliceAction). The function is incredibly straightforward but getting TypeScript to recognize the keys has embarrassingly tripped me up.

I'm following along with the example from [Redux Toolkit's tutorial](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/advanced-tutorial) but I wanted to see if this were possible. Ideally, I'll be able to use the function in conjunction with either Redux-Saga or Redux-Observable to avoid using string literals as action types.

I've setup a **[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-moore-4wuol?file=/src/App.tsx:1149-1474)** with my attempt.

```
const getActions = <T extends Slice>(slice: T) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(slice.actions) as Array<keyof typeof slice.actions>;
  return keys.reduce(
    (accumulator, key) => {
      accumulator[key] = `${slice.name}/${key}`;
      return accumulator;
    },
    {} as Record<keyof typeof slice.actions, string>
  );
};
```

The intent is to be able to take a slice like this:

```
const issuesDisplaySlice = createSlice({
  name: "issuesDisplay",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    displayRepo(state, action: PayloadAction<CurrentRepo>) {
      //...
    },
    setCurrentPage(state, action: PayloadAction<number>) {
      //...
    }
  }
});
```

and get a TypeScript to recognize the output to be:

```
{
  displayRepo: string,
  setCurrentPage: string
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this and I especially appreciate anyone who takes the time to try and solve it. I know your time is valuable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your codesandbox code, it seems that `keyof typeof slice.actions` is not sufficiently generic to express what you're trying to do.  Even though `slice` is a of generic type `T` extending `Slice`, when you evaluate `slice.actions`, the compiler treats it as if it were just `Slice`:

```
const actions = slice.actions; // CaseReducerActions<SliceCaseReducers<any>>
```

And that's unfortunate because `keyof CaseReducerActions<SliceCaseReducers<any>>` (aka `keyof Slice['actions']`) is just `string | number` and not the specific keys you've passed in on `T`:

```
type KeyofSliceActions = keyof Slice['actions'];
// type KeyofSliceActions = string | number
```

---

Widening generic values to their constraints upon property lookup is probably good for performance, but leads to some undesirable situations like this one.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181) for the relevant issue.

Ideally, when you look up the `actions` property on a value of type `T`, the compiler would treat the result as the [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) `T['actions']` instead.  This doesn't happen *automatically*, but you can ask the compiler to do it with a type annotation:

```
const genericActions: T['actions'] = slice.actions;  // this is acceptable
```

Now, if you replace instances of `slice.actions` in the rest of your code with `genericActions`, the typings will work the way you want them:

```
const getActions = <T extends Slice>(slice: T) => {
  const genericActions: T['actions'] = slice.actions;  // this is acceptable
  const keys = Object.keys(genericActions) as Array<keyof typeof genericActions>;
  return keys.reduce(
    (accumulator, key) => {
      accumulator[key] = `${slice.name}/${key}`;
      return accumulator;
    },
    {} as Record<keyof typeof genericActions, string>
  );
};

// const getActions: <T extends Slice<any, SliceCaseReducers<any>, string>>(
//   slice: T) => Record<keyof T["actions"], string>
```

(Aside: `keyof typeof genericActions` can be shortened to `keyof T['actions']`.)  You can see that `getActions()` now returns `Record<keyof T["actions"], string>`, a type that depends on `T`.

Let's see if it works:

```
const actions = getActions<typeof issuesDisplaySlice>(issuesDisplaySlice);
// const actions: Record<"displayRepo" | "setCurrentPage" | "setCurrentDisplayType", string>

actions.displayRepo.toUpperCase(); // okay
actions.displayTypo.toUpperCase(); // error!
// ---> ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'displayTypo' does not exist on type 
// 'Record<"displayRepo" | "setCurrentPage" | "setCurrentDisplayType", string>'.
// Did you mean 'displayRepo'?
```

Looks good to me. Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwCwAUI6JLHAN5y6XIxYDKAG2C4sAGjgAFZAE9BEZABMAgvmAQAdhKEiscAL5wiJcgAFKigK4APAFaoA9DAgRBAa2AxajZhr5QCPD0AYUsoSj8AEWBUMEFZDkY4OEUYuNkAFRkwLAAuchjUSyxUMjgAH3JcEhAsP1L6BmTC4oBJRXyNSxAAIywoCrguwUFG-R8GYD9+wNE4UPC6mGjY+JlpOQVFRKaUtLWsnPyyFpKyyrJqkFr6713T9oB+Tu6+qDGJqf9ZkLCImGwkB2yWgAHN8qgYFApqDGslKJAIVCYR8mAwYNlfosovtZPwYLw9ABeYFwMDIUF5IavfpjOAAMnmfyWK3SMgZSSZ2IBWEgjUYgiw8CmnmAyEE+MJ+QW-1Za0lfDgJPYnLBxygyGAglKYk5CIg6s12rIut25Mp+QAjKbkqlVplMcdTjrOQ8OtSRox9Py0dUNJC4M65XjhHMSdwcHwdKIABQq3YaZC1J2oIolYMyE2ujSi8UK8R6rBWURQVD5ePJW24mSAiAxyGEiR4GDqDT5DbyJSqFuaAA8MqWtYAfABKUmVriaAOcMESfUGJUoNSaAB05M2SjhE7gDb4K7Bi7BW4nu6wK-nJP1x4MNsrqCFA780kp9YJfCby7bUlknZUn97XS9P0o7jneb5nuaxJLj2Ghrj+WzXvot7JPeMCPss1aHFgr6NtBrbtvBXb-uhGYdlsIEVtufrTns9oyFhEhuouwyCAuJLNq2cEboo14oeBK52myWGLoJByYrxO78UxJJuohnLjAw+gjj6GI5HAADSWAyBABDRlg3atugJJuFpOlwHpADaADkHFTlZAC6jQOA4cCqXomnabpob6Z+RmSdCGigoMgFvBM1HwJSMAGVOi69hkcBYNYfAaIo6B6UO9befkGRjkSQ6kuFcCUho-QiNF-rZdZtn+g5i6oN5K7VagNDJM5rkABYxIG6B4KIYAEj0gqcoVJkyH5ADyPS2Fg+ArqNqAxsVpW4OVqBjmgcDKOEsi9qNZluWZS3QitvlDlulAwGEGhwPN55FpYsacskMa9d0ljxM4UASKNuX5ZRE6vSA728NAFmjfZi4AAYACTsPVugromtT6A4sOjfokMSRdV1Lrgb0fdAiHIRwhgbdg1RQIou2mQQrmYoddTLatEiQgFoJDpyylek5LmFZFq35HFCVJXUqXmd5vbIBoMjaN5wRoFg2DFv0qCS9LQ4s8igVDhlcCMG1KFZXAOVKvl5PQFTe20xkFlkE1ZD2ZrbMc2ijCFU1i7875vYHbTQbVulMb+3RelcwwbXu75+Tm5TvZkKJsi1uc5Coehz5YMnZCp8yOJ0VhJr+TCLuME1AnVrWK7OAAqmAORQPL94xspcBtRAbiyCXvll3n2QQJXEA13XDfYc3bX9MQUAAIT6y5AC08-5QAfsvK+r4vM9SMQdcYnAVkJ-RvdWSkEAlEMEDwIlMTwJodNqRvVkx1T8fl7yECZ9n3Lp+-D45xhPc5AXVmRcrIrg3tEbY2lLBwFqFLXe+9axWUeBMRKrB4CKCwIEd6hBLAaE-JtWuTdSTYygNdGMT04C9lSAANy4PEVMAA5JMWAiRkGULXMgLttwUOoZwrhFCwCUCHOwAAUvwca9CVxAMCsAAgMgXq+QkCxCQAAmEc+hewOAEVgXhE4NE8PIckeeRiDH8MEaXeBr9yzmJfpAdRmjBHkL0cAKhvCw4KSAA)

Comment: I forgot to comment on this. That's awesome man, thank you so much!